Programmatically check there a "disk image password" in KeyChain
On my macOS app I would like to know whether the user has defined a password in the KeyChain for a given encrypted Disk Image. I do not want to know the password itself. I just need to know whether the password is in the KeyChain or not.
I can clearly see the password is on the KeyChain.app, as

name: "MyDisk.dmg"
kind: "disk image password"
Account: D0899FA8-C……
Access Group: com.apple.DisklmagesKeychainGroup

So, from my macOS app I unsuccessfully tried to get that item using SecItemCopyMatching with any kind of kSecClass: kSecClassInternetPassword, kSecClassGenericPassword, kSecClassCertificate, kSecClassKey, kSecClassIdentity.
NSDictionary *query = @{
       (__bridge NSString*)kSecClass : (__bridge NSString*)kSecClassGenericPassword,
       (__bridge NSString*)kSecReturnAttributes: (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
       (__bridge NSString*)kSecMatchLimit : (NSString*)kSecMatchLimitAll
    };

NSArray *items = nil;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef*)&items);

I get any kind of item but no one reports MyDisk.dmg or any other data that can drive me to the MyDisk.dmg volume.
Even if it should return just the NSURL credentials, I also unsuccessfully tried
NSDictionary *credentials = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] allCredentials];

And I event tried, unsuccessfully
security dump-keychain -d login.keychain

How can I know that there is a keychain item for a given Disk Image Password, a Local Disk Password and a Remote Disk Password?
I run macOS 15.1 and XCode 16.1.
